# git config with branch name with forward slashes

Tags: git, git-config

I have a branch name with forward slashes:

```
oleg/feature/foo
```

if I try to run:

```
git config --local branch.oleg/feature/foo.bar 5
```

I get this:

> `error: invalid key: branch.oleg/feature/foo`

even though when I run `git branch` I see that

```
oleg/feature/foo
```

is listed...what to do?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this behavior.  What shell are you working in?

Comment: bash on ubuntu, I got rid of the slashes and it worked. Underscores also caused problems...weird right? why would underscores cause problems?

Comment: Works for me with git version 2.11.0, bash on debian. What is your `git --version`?

Comment: This should work. One oddity above: the *key* should be `bar` which is in a *section* `[branch "oleg/feature/foo"]` with `bar = 5` under it. Note that valid characters are alphanumerics plus `-`, with the first character of the key required to be alphabetical (`isalpha()`). When `git config` complains about an invalid key, it prints the entire section-plus-key string. Section names are less constrained than key names since Git needs to put submodule paths into them.

Comment: ok so since _ underscore and / are not alphanumerics that is one reason why it fails?